# Remove \r (CR) from CSV

Tags: macos, csv, sed, newline

On OSX I need to remove line-ending CR (`\r`) characters (represented as `^M` in the output from `cat -v`)  from my CSV file:

```
$ cat -v myitems.csv
```

output:

```
strPicture,strEmail^M
image1xl.jpg,me@example.com^M
```

I have tried lots of options with sed and perl but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it will fix your issue.

```
dos2unix myitems.csv myitems.csv
```

Comment: `dos2unix` is not available by default on OSX, but [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) users can get it via `brew install dos2unix`. However: `dos2unix` defaults to converting files *in place*, so you probably just want `dos2unix myitems.csv` (specifying the file a 2nd time will simply attempt to convert it again). By contrast, if you want to write to a different output file, use `dos2unix -n myitems.csv new-myitems.csv` (applies to OSX an Linux versions).

Answer (score 5):

**Solutions with stock utilities**:

<sup>Note: Except where noted (the `sed -i` incompatibility), the following solutions work on both OSX (macOS) and Linux.</sup>

**Use `sed`** as follows, which replaces `\r\n` with `\n`:

```sh
sed $'s/\r$//' myitems.csv
```

To update the input file *in place*, use

```sh
sed -i '' $'s/\r$//' myitems.csv
```

<sup>`-i ''` specifies updating in place, with `''` indicating that *no backup* should be made of the input file; if you specify a extension, e.g., `-i'.bak'`, the *original* input file will be saved with that extension as a backup.

*Caveats*:

* With ***GNU* `sed` (Linux)**, to not create a backup file, you'd have to use **just `-i`, without the separate `''` argument**, which is **an unfortunate syntactic incompatibility between GNU Sed and the BSD Sed** used on OSX (macOS) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777793/45375) of mine for the full story.

* `-i` creates a new file with a temporary name and then replaces the original file; the most notably consequence is that if the original file was a *symlink*, it is replaced with a regular file; for a detailed discussion, see the lower half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375).</sup>

Note: The above uses an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`) to create the `\r` character in the `sed` command, because BSD `sed` (the one used on OS X), doesn't natively recognize such escape sequences (note that the *GNU* `sed` used on Linux distros would).
ANSI C-quoted strings are supported in Bash, Ksh, and Zsh.

If you don't want to rely on such strings, use:

```sh
sed 's/'"$(printf '\r')"'$//'
```

Here, the `\r` is created via `printf` and spliced into the `sed` command with a command substitution (`$(...)`).

---

**Using `perl`:**

```sh
perl -pe 's/\r\n/\n/' myitems.csv | cat -v
```

To update the input file *in place*, use

```sh
perl -i -ple 's/\r\n/\n/' myitems.csv  # -i'.bak' creates backup with suffix '.bak' first
```

<sup>The same caveat as above for `sed` with regard to in-place updating applies.</sup>

---

**Using `awk`:**

```sh
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' myitems.csv  # shorter: awk 'sub("\r$", "")+1'
```

BSD `awk` offers no in-place updating option, so you'll have to capture the output in a different file; to use a temporary file and have it replace the original afterward, use the following idiom:

```sh
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' myitems.csv > tmpfile && mv tmpfile myitems.csv
```

<sup>*GNU* `awk` v4.1 or higher offers `-i inplace` for in-place updating, to which the same caveat as above for `sed` applies.</sup>

---

<sup>Edge case for all variants above: If the very last char. in the input file happens to be a lone `\r` without a following `\n`, it will also be replaced with a `\n`.</sup>

---

For the sake of completeness: here are **additional, possibly suboptimal solutions**:

<sup>None of them offer in-place updating, but you can employ the `> tmpfile && mv tmpfile myitems.csv` idiom introduced above</sup>

---

**Using `tr`**: a very simple solution that simply removes *all* `\r` instances; thus, it can only be used if `\r` instance *only* occur as part of `\r\`n sequences; typically, however, that *is* the case:

```sh
tr -d '\r' < myitems.csv
```

---

**Using pure `bash` code**: note that this will be *slow*; like the `tr` solution, this can only be used if `\r` instance *only* occur as part of `\r\n` sequences.

```sh
while IFS=$'\r' read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < myitems.csv
```

`$IFS` is the internal field separator, and setting it to `\r` causes `read` to read everything before `\r`, if present, into variable `$line` (if there's no `\r`, the line is read as is). `-r` prevents `read` from interpreting `\` instances in the input.

<sup>Edge case: If the input doesn't end with `\n`, the *last line will not print* - you could fix that by using `read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]`.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Try the unix2dos command.

Example: unix2dos infile outfile

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos

The wikipedia page has some examples using perl and sed too.

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\n/\r\n/' file
sed -i -e 's/$/\r/' file
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to go in the opposite direction - DOS -> Unix - the original wording wasn't clear, but the presence of `^M` in the output from `cat -v` as well as the OSX reference suggest that it's about removing `\r` (CR) characters.