# Using Awk or Sed to tack on a statement at the end of a specific line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file I named `poscar1.cif`, and I would like to insert the contents of a variable at a specific line in this file.

For example, line `24`, which currently reads:

```
_cell_length_a
```

I would like to tack the contents of my variable `a` (defined in my function as `a=5.3827`) so that way the line now reads:

```
_cell_length_a 5.3827
```

Is there a way to do this using sed or awk? I am using a bash script to accomplish this (the full script is too large to post, unfortunately).

Comment: Is it actually line 24 or the pattern that matches `_cell_length_a`?

Answer (score 7):

Since the veteran **[ed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)** utility doesn't get enough attention anymore:

```
a=5.3827

ed -s poscar1.cif <<EOF 
g/^_cell_length_a\$/ s//& $a/
w
EOF
```

`ed` truly edits a file *in place*, unlike `sed` with its `-i` option<sup>[1]</sup>.

`sed` borrowed many features from `ed`, so there is significant overlap in functionality, but there are also important differences, some of which surface here.

- `-s` suppresses `ed`'s status messages.
- `poscar1.cif` is the input file to edit in place.
- `<<EOF ...` is the [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) that contains the commands for `ed` - `ed` requires its commands to come from *stdin* and each command to be on its own line.
- `g/^_cell_length_a\$/` ... is a (basic) regex (regular expression) that matches all lines that exactly contain `_cell_length_a` - the `g` ensures that no error is reported if there's no match at all.

  - Note that the `$` is `\`-escaped to protect it from interpretation by the *shell* inside the here-document (not strictly necessary in *this* instance, but good practice).
- `s//& $a/` ... `//` repeats the search for the most recently used regex on a matching line and replaces the match with itself (`&`), followed by a space and the value of variable `$a`.

  - Note that since the opening delimiter (`EOF`) of the here-document is *unquoted*, *shell* variable expansions DO take place; in essence, the contents are treated by the shell like the contents of a double-quoted string.
- `w` writes the modified buffer back to the input file.

  - For debugging, use `,p` in place of `w` so as to only *print* the modified buffer, without writing it back to the file.

---

[1] **Re in-place updating:**

More precisely, **`ed` preserves the file's existing *inode*, which ensures that all *the file's attributes are preserved.***
However, it does *not* overwrite individual bytes of the existing file, but **reads the *entire* file into a buffer in memory**, and writes the entire buffer to the file when asked to.
This makes **`ed` suitable only for files small enough to be read into memory as a whole**.

By contrast, **`sed -i`** (*GNU* and *BSD* `sed`), its *GNU* 4.1+ counterpart, **`awk -i inplace`**, and also **`perl -i`** ***replace* the original file with a *newly created* one**, which implies that they:

- **destroy symlinks(!)** - if the input file was a *symlink*, it is *replaced with a regular file* of the same name

  - A common scenario where that matters: say your shell initialization file `~/.bashrc` is a *symlink* to a file elsewhere you keep under source control; you then install a tool that uses `sed -i` to modify `~/.bashrc`, which results in it being replaced with a regular file, and the link to your source-controlled version is broken.
  - What's more, BSD `sed`'s behavior even introduces a security risk (see below).
- do **not** preserve the **original file-creation date** (where supported; e.g., on OSX)
- they **do**, however,

  - preserve **extended attributes** (where supported; e.g., on OSX)
  - preserve file **permissions**

    - Caution: **BSD `sed`** introduces a **security risk** with respect to **symlinks** (behavior still present as of the version that comes with FreeBSD 10):

      - The *symlink*'s permissions are copied to the replacement file, not the symlink *target*'s. Since symlinks get *executable* permissions by default, **you'll invariably end up with an *executable* file**, whether the input file was executable or not.
    - Fortunately, *GNU* `sed` handles this scenario properly.

`sed`, `gawk`, and `perl` *could* address the issues above by taking extra steps, but there's **one thing that can only be ensured if the original inode is retained, as `ed` does**:

**When a file is being monitored for changes** by its inode number (e.g., with `tail -f`), not preserving the inode breaks that monitoring.

Comment: `ed` The standard editor : https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html . Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter: Great fun; I particularly enjoyed, "Ed is generous enough to flag errors, yet prudent enough not to overwhelm the novice with verbosity."

Comment: Yes "generous enough ..." is my favorite part too!

Comment: wrt `ed truly edits a file in place` - no it doesn't. `ed` reads the whole input file into an internal buffer and operates on that and then writes that buffer back to the original file which is no more useful than copying it to a tmp file. It's like in awk if you read the whole input file into an array or string then close the input file and operate on that buffer and then write it back out to the original file. To really edit a file in place (e.g. if you need to edit a 2G file with only 1M of memory available) you need to use `dd` and some magical incantations.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, it reads the whole file into a buffer first; I didn't mean to imply that individual bytes are rewritten, so I've clarified. However, what matters is preserving the original inode, as `ed` does: this can make a crucial difference; I've contrasted `ed`'s behavior with both `sed -i` and `awk -i inplace` in my update; please let me know if you'd like me to add / correct something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed to do it, depending on your answer to dawg's question as

```
sed -i -e '24s/$/5.3827/' poscar1.cif
```

or if it's the pattern

```
sed -i -e '/_cell_length_a/s/$/5.3827/' poscar1.cif
```

The first goes to the line with the given number, the later will apply on any line that matches the pattern in the first set of slashes.  In either case it will then "replace" the end of the line with the value between the final two slashes.

Comment: Nicely done; note that `-i` without an option-argument (indicating that _no_ backup be made) is _GNU_ `sed`-specific. _BSD_ `sed` would require `-i ''`, and a strictly POSIX-compliant `sed` wouldn't support `-i` at all.

Comment: P.S.: You're missing a space before `5.3827` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

Using your example, you could do something like this:

```
sed -i 's/\(_cell_length_a\)/\1 5.3827/' poscar1.cif
```

where,

- the `-i` option says to edit the file in place, rather than creating a copy
- the funky looking quoted part is a string specifying a regular expression aka regex
- `poscar1.cif` is the file

The regex syntax is hard to read. The basic format to find and replace is:

```
s/find/replace/
```

Where `find` is the text of the line you're looking for and `replace` is the text to replace that text with.

If we want to use part of the find string in our replacement, we group it by surrounding it with `\(` and `\)` and then use `\1` to refer to it in the replacement string. The following appends replace to any line consisting of find:

```
s/\(find\)/\1replace/
```

Keep in mind that there are special escape characters or meta characters that you have to treat specially if your string contains them.

Comment: Nicely done; note that if the _entire_ regex is to be replaced, there's no need to use `\(` and `\)` to create a capture group; simply refer to the entire match as `&` in the replacement string.
Also, note that `-i` without an option-argument (indicating that _no_ backup be made) is _GNU_ `sed`-specific. _BSD_ `sed` would require `-i ''`, and a strictly POSIX-compliant `sed` wouldn't support `-i` at all.