# How to type ^@ in the shell prompt

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a requirement to remove all the control character displayed as "^@" in a list of files.

In the VI editor mode to type the control character ^@ we need to press CTRL+V+@
But the same is not working in the shell prompt.
Please help me on this.

Note : I tried in Debian linux machine.

Comment: Nope, you have to press `Ctrl`+`V` followed by `Ctrl`+`@`. Depending on your keymap, this can be a challenge (e.g. on French keyboards we have to type `Ctrl`+`V` followed by `Ctrl`+`AltGr`+`à`).

Comment: For those confused by the notation, the OP is talking about null bytes (0x00). ;-)

Comment: Why are you removing them instead of re-encoding the files using `iconv` or the like?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at in Vim are "null" bytes, i.e. bytes with the numeric value zero.

You can check that by putting the cursor on top of that `^@` and typing `ga`. This displays the numeric value of the character under the cursor.

If you need to remove all occurrences of that character from a file, you can use `sed`, and you don't need to type `^@` for that at all, since `sed` (at least the GNU version, not the BSD one it seems...) supports a different notation for hex values:

```
sed "s/\x00//g" file.txt
```

That would print the contents of `file.txt` to stdout, all zero bytes removed. If you want to remove the bytes in-place (be careful, dangerous to your orignial file, and also (1)!), use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i "s/\x00//g" file.txt
```

---

(1) Check [the answer by gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33348796/60281) (and the comments) on the caveats re `sed`: You will lose the file creation date, and you need to be sure it's really a *file* you're working on, not a symlink.

---

For completeness, you can of course remove zero bytes *without* leaving Vim.

```
:%s/<ctrl-v>x00//g
```

- `:` command mode
- `%` range: complete file
- `s/` search
- `<ctrl-v>` verbatim
- `x` hexadecimal
- `00` zero
- `/` replace with...
- `/` ...nothing
- `g` globally (multiple times per line)

---

All this is of course assuming that you are not looking at an UTF-16 file and just being confused by the zero bytes in there. If that's the case, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams hint at [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) is of course the better way: `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 file.txt`. But then, Vim shouldn't be showing you `^@` in the first place.

Comment: To explain why _BSD_ `sed` (and any POSIX-features-only implementation) cannot do it (do tell me if you know of a way): Seemingly, the only escape sequence supported in a regex is `\n` - no way to represent `NUL`.

Comment: @mklement0: I have no access to BSD at the moment, but it seems the **AIX** version of `sed` just removes null bytes in any case, whether your regex matches them or not. :-D

Answer (score 2):

`^@` is the null byte (`0x00`). To remove this from a file, you likely want to use a genuine editor and not a program that will create a temporary file and then `mv` that temp file to the original one: you'd lose all permissions, ownerships and symlinks.

Here's how you can remove all null bytes from a file with `ed`, the standard editor:

```
ed -s file < <(printf ',s/\0//g\nw\nq\n')
```

If you want to use this with, e.g., `find`, you'll have to proceed thus:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'for f do ed -s "$f" < <(printf ',s/\0//g\nw\nq\n'); done' bash {} +
```

Comment: @mklement0: How is this "more robust" than e.g. `sed -i`?

Comment: @DevSolar I guess he means what I wrote in the answer: with `sed`, _you'd lose all permissions, ownerships and symlinks._

Comment: @DevSolar yes, `sed -i` creates a temporary file and then `mv` this temp file on the original one. Try it `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I did, and it doesn't.

Comment: @DevSolar: For a comprehensive look, see the bottom half of my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375. In short:  permissions _are_ preserved, but symlinks are destroyed, the file-_creation_ date is lost, and, on OSX, extended file attributes are lost.

Comment: I stand corrected on the symlinks and the file creation date. I just tested the first part of your claim ("you'd lose all permissions"), which is false, and didn't bother to test further. You correct that, and you'll get my upvote as well, and thanks for teaching me something today. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: Also note that GNU `awk -i inplace` and `perl -i` have the same issues.

Comment: Small caveat: even though [`ed` is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), it is sadly not on all platforms; Debian is a notably exception; I think there are also platforms where `ed` is a symlink to a different utility.

Comment: @mklement0: At this point I figured as much, but I don't grok `awk`, and don't use `perl` for oneliners. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not going to correct that, my statement was about methods not involving a genuine editor: and this includes explicit `mv` too, like for example the `tr` method (which is actually very good). Regarding `sed -i`: note that it's not specified by POSIX, so nothing guarantees that there's an implementation out there that doesn't deal properly with permissions; moreover I'm not sure how `sed -i` handles ACLs (but that's beyond the scope of this question anyway). (Btw, I did upvote your answer).

Comment: @mklement0 yeah, this thing about Debian sucks (and their default editor is `nano` too). The first thing to do on a fresh install is `sudo apt-get install ed`.

Comment: @mklement0: I don't know about `ed`, but `vim` installs `ex` as an alias to itself, starting in `ex` mode if invoked that way. gniourf_gniourf: Any particular reason why you'd go for `ed` instead of `vim` in `ex` mode? (Just wondering, because `vim` is usually the first thing *I* install on a new box. :-D )

Comment: @DevSolar no particular reason to prefer `ed` over `ex` (just that for this task `ex` is overkill). Anyway, in `ex` you'd do: `ex file < <(printf '%%s/\\%%x00//g\nwq\n')` (untested).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: For *in-place editing* solutions, see [gniourf_gniourf's `ed`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33348796/45375) (most robust) or [DevSolar's *GNU* `sed`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33348696/45375).</sup>

`^@` is used to represent `NUL` (`0x`) bytes, both in `vi` and in `cat -v`'s output.

**In case you need to remove the *actual* `NUL` characters** from your files, you don't need to type `^@`; **use `tr -d '\0'`** instead:

```
# Create sample file with embedded NUL chars.
echo 'before NUL' > file;  head -c 2 </dev/zero >> file; echo 'after NUL' >>file
```

Examining the file with `cat -v` shows us (note the `^@` representing the `NUL` chars; `$` represents a newline):

```
$ cat -v file
before NUL
^@^@after NUL
```

`tr -d '\0' < file` will print the contents of `file` with all `NUL` chars. removed:

```
$ tr -d '\0' < file | cat -v
before NUL$
after NUL$
```