# Why does "sed -n -i" delete existing file contents?

Tags: sed, gnu-sed

Running Fedora 25 server edition. `sed --version` gives me `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` along with the usual copyright and contact info. I've create a text file `sudo vi ./potential_sed_bug`. Vi shows the contents of this file (with `:set list` enabled) as:

```
don't$
delete$
me$
please$
```

I then run the following command:

`sudo sed -n -i.bak /please/a\testing ./potential_sed_bug`

Before we discuss the results; here is what the [sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) says:

> -n, --quiet, --silent
>   suppress automatic printing of pattern space

and

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>   edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied). The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links. This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.

I've also looked [other sed command references](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to learn how to append with sed. Based on my understanding from the research I've done; the resulting file content should be:

```
don't
delete
me
please
testing
```

However, running `sudo cat ./potential_sed_bug` gives me the following output:

```
testing
```

In light of this discrepancy, is my understanding of the command I ran incorrect or is there a bug with sed/the environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Don't use `-n` with `-i`: unless you use explicit output commands in your `sed` script, nothing will be written to your file.
- Using `-i` produces *no* stdout (terminal) output, so there's nothing extra you need to do to make your command quiet.

---

By default, `sed` automatically prints the (possibly modified) input lines to whatever its output target is, whether implied or explicitly specified: by default, to *stdout* (the terminal, unless redirected); with `-i`, to a *temporary file* that ultimately replaces the input file.

In *both* cases, `-n` *suppresses* this automatic printing, so that - unless you use explicit output functions such as `p` or, in your case, `a` - *nothing* gets printed to stdout / written to the temporary file.

- Note that the automatic printing applies to the so-called *pattern space*, which is where the (possibly modified) *input* is held; explicit output functions such as `p`, `a`, `i` and `c` do *not* print to the pattern space (for potential subsequent modification), they print *directly to the target stream / file*, which is why `a\testing` was able to produce output, despite the use of `-n`.

Note that with `-i`, `sed`'s implicit printing / explicit output commands *only* print to the temporary file, and not also to stdout, so a command using `-i` is invariably quiet with respect to stdout (terminal) output - there's nothing extra you need to do.

---

To give a concrete example (*GNU* `sed` syntax).

<sup>Since the use of `-i` is incidental to the question, I've omitted it for simplicity. Note that `-i` prints to a *temporary file* first, which, on completion, *replaces* the original. This comes with *pitfalls*, notably the potential destruction of symlinks; see the lower half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375) of mine.</sup>

```
# Print input (by default), and append literal 'testing' after 
# lines that contain 'please'.
$ sed '/please/ a testing' <<<$'yes\nplease\nmore'
yes
please
testing
more

# Adding `-n` suppresses the default printing, so only `testing` is printed.
# Note that the sequence of processing is exactly the same as without `-n`:
# If and when a line with 'please' is found, 'testing' is appended *at that time*.
$ sed -n '/please/ a testing' <<<$'yes\nplease\nmore'
testing

# Adding an unconditional `p` (print) call undoes the effect of `-n`.
$ sed -n 'p; /please/ a testing' <<<$'yes\nplease\nmore'
yes
please
testing
more
```

Comment: What is interesting to me is that I have always considered `sed -e cmd1 | sed -e cmd2` equivalent to `sed -e cmd1 -e cmd2` but this is an area where you would actually want to pipe sed to sed if for some reason what you are appending is a context that you later want to modify.  I guess `n` and `q` other commands would break that equivalence too.