# shell script replace variables in file - error with Sed's -i option for in-place updating

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ex, inplace-editing

Here is my `test.env`

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=127.0.0.1
RABBITMQ_PASS=1234
```

And I want to use `test.sh`  to replace the value in `test.env` to :

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq1
RABBITMQ_PASS=12345
```

here is my **test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"

RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq1
RABBITMQ_PASS=12345
Deploy_path="./config/test.env"

sed -i 's/RABBITMQ_HOST=.*/RABBITMQ_HOST='$RABBITMQ_HOST'/'  $Deploy_path
sed -i 's/RABBITMQ_PASS=.*/RABBITMQ_PASS='$RABBITMQ_HOST'/'  $Deploy_path
```

But I have error

```
sed: 1: "./config/test.env": invalid command code .
sed: 1: "./config/test.env": invalid command code .
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which sed are you using?

Comment: [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) is directly on-point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

With ***BSD* Sed**, such as also found on **macOS**, you **must use `-i ''` instead of just `-i`** (for not creating a backup file) to make your commands work; e.g.:

```
sed -i '' 's/RABBITMQ_HOST=.*/RABBITMQ_HOST='"$RABBITMQ_HOST"'/'  "$Deploy_path"
```

To make your command **work with *both* GNU and BSD Sed**, specify a ***nonempty* option-argument** (which creates a backup) and ***attach it directly* to `-i`**:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/RABBITMQ_HOST=.*/RABBITMQ_HOST='"$RABBITMQ_HOST"'/'  "$Deploy_path" &&
  rm "$Deploy_path.bak" # remove unneeded backup copy
```

Background information, (more) portable solutions, and refinement of your commands can be found below.

---

#### Optional Background Information

It sounds like you're using *BSD/macOS* `sed`, whose `-i` option *requires* an option-argument that specifies the suffix of the backup file to create.
Therefore, it is your `sed` *script* that (against your expectations) is interpreted as `-i`'s *option-argument* (the backup suffix), and your input *filename* is interpreted as the *script*, which obviously fails.

By contrast, your commands use *GNU* `sed` syntax, where `-i` can be used by itself to indicate that *no* backup file of the input file to updated in-place is to be kept.

The equivalent *BSD* `sed` option is `-i ''` - note the *technical* need to use a *separate* argument to specify the option-argument `''`, because it is the empty string (if you used `-i''`, the shell would simply strip the `''` before `sed` ever sees it: `-i''` is effectively the same as just `-i`).

Sadly, this then won't work with *GNU* `sed`, because it only recognizes the option-argument when *directly attached* to `-i`, and would interpret the separate `''` as a separate argument, namely as the *script*.

This difference in behavior stems from a fundamentally differing design decision behind the implementation of the `-i` option and it probably won't go away for reasons of backward compatibility.<sup>[1]</sup>

**If you do *not* want a backup file created, there is no single `-i` syntax that works for *both* BSD and GNU `sed`.**

There are four basic options:

- (a) If you know that you'll only be using *either* GNU *or* BSD `sed`, construct the `-i` option accordingly: `-i` for GNU `sed`, `-i ''` for BSD `sed`.
- (b) Specify a *nonempty* suffix as `-i`'s option-argument, which, if you attach it *directly* to the `-i` option, works with *both* implementations; e.g., `-i'.bak'`.  While this invariably creates a backup file with suffix `.bak`, you can just delete it afterward.
- (c) Determine at runtime which `sed` implementation you're dealing with and construct the `-i` option accordingly.
- (d) omit `-i` (which is not POSIX-compliant) altogether, and use a temporary file that replaces the original on success: `sed '...' "$Deploy_path" > tmp.out && mv tmp.out "$Deploy_path"`.
  Note that this is in essence what `-i` does behind the scenes, which can have unexpected side effects, notably an input file that is a *symlink* getting replaced with a *regular* file; `-i`, does, however, preserve certain attributes of the original file: see the lower half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375) of mine.

Here's a `bash` implementation of (c) that also streamlines the original code (single `sed` invocation with 2 substitutions) and makes it more robust (variables are double-quoted):

```
#!/bin/bash

RABBITMQ_HOST='rabbitmq1'
RABBITMQ_PASS='12345'
Deploy_path="test.env"

# Construct the Sed-implementation-specific -i option-argument.
# Caveat: The assumption is that if the `sed` is not GNU Sed, it is BSD Sed,
#         but there are Sed implementations that don't support -i at all,
#         because, as Steven Penny points out, -i is not part of POSIX.
suffixArg=()
sed --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q GNU || suffixArg=( '' )

sed -i "${suffixArg[@]}" '
 s/^\(RABBITMQ_HOST\)=.*/\1='"$RABBITMQ_HOST"'/
 s/^\(RABBITMQ_PASS\)=.*/\1='"$RABBITMQ_PASS"'/
' "$Deploy_path"
```

Note that with the specific values defined above for `$RABBITMQ_HOST` and `$RABBITMQ_PASS`, it is safe to splice them directly into the `sed` script, but if the values contained instances of `&`, `/`, `\`, or newlines, prior escaping would be required so as not to break the `sed` command.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375) of mine for how to perform generic pre-escaping, but you may also consider other tools at that point, such as `awk` and `perl`.

---

<sup>[1] GNU Sed considers the option-argument to -i *optional*, whereas BSD Sed considers it *mandatory*, which is also reflected in the syntax specs. in the respective `man` pages: GNU Sed: `-i[SUFFIX]` vs. BSD Sed  `-i extension`.</sup>

Comment: for sed `-i` version differences, I usually just point them to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201611240550488009289

Answer (score 1):

```
ex -sc '%!awk "\
\$1 == \"RABBITMQ_HOST\" && \$2 = \"rabbitmq1\"\
\$1 == \"RABBITMQ_PASS\" && \$2 = 12345\
" FS== OFS==' -cx file
```

1. [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) does not support the `-i` option. However ex can edit files
   in place
2. Awk is a better tool for this, as the data is separated into records and
   fields
3. In either case Sed or Awk, you can utilize a newline or `;` to do everything
   in one invocation
4. You have double quoted strings with no variables inside, might as well use
   single quotes
5. You quoted your file name when it has no characters that need escaping
6. You have several unquoted uses of variables, almost never a good idea

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Case**

If `test.env` contains only the two variables, you can simply create a new file, or overwrite existing:

```
printf "RABBITMQ_HOST=%s\nRABBITMQ_PASS=%s\n" \
  "${RABBITMQ_HOST}" "${RABBITMQ_PASS}" > "$Deploy_path"
```

**Fixing Unquoted Variables and Optimizing the SED Commands**

Try to fix your command as follows:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(RABBITMQ_HOST=\).*/\1'"$RABBITMQ_HOST"'/' \
  -e 's/\(RABBITMQ_PASS=\).*/\1'"$RABBITMQ_PASS"'/' \
  "$Deploy_path"
```

You should enclose the variables in double quotes, since otherwise the shell will interpret the contents. In a content in double quotes, the shell will interpret only `$` (replacing the variable with its content), backquote, and `\` (escape). Also note the use of multiple `-e` options.

**Why SED is Bad for this Task (*in my Opinion*)?**

But, as it is said in *@mklement0*'s answer, `-i` might not work in this form on BSD systems. Also, the command only *modifies* the two variables, if they are defined in `$Deploy_path` file, if the file exists. It will not add *new variables* into the file. Be warned, the variables are embedded directly into the replacement, and their *values*, generally, should be escaped according to the SED rules!

**Alternative**

If the `test.env` file is *trusted*, I recommend to load the variables, modify them and print to the output file:

```
(
  # Load variables from test.env
  source test.env

  # Override some variables
  RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq1
  RABBITMQ_PASS=12345

  # Print all variables prefixed with "RABBITMQ_".
  # In POSIX mode, `set` will not output defines and functions
  set -o posix
  set | grep ^RABBITMQ_
) > "$Deploy_path"
```

Consider adjusting the file system permissions for `test.env`. I suppose, the source file is a trusted template.

The solution without SED is better, in my opinion, because the SED implementations may vary, and the in-place option may not work as expected on different platforms.

**But, isn't `source` risky?**

While parsing the shell variable assignments is usually an easy task, it is more risky than just sourcing the ready-for-use "script" (*test.env*). For instance, consider the following line in your `test.env`:

```
declare RABBITMQ_HOST=${MYVAR:=rabbitmq1}
```

or

```
export RABBITMQ_HOST=host
```

All of the currently suggested solutions, except the code using `source`, assume that you assign the variable as `RABBITMQ_HOST=...`. Some of the solutions even assume that `RABBIT_HOST` is placed at the beginning of the line. Ahh, you might fix the regular expression then, right? Just for *this* case...

Thus, `source` is risky as much as the file being sourced is not trusted. Think of `#include <file>` in C, or `include "file.php"` in PHP. These instructions include the source into the current source as well. So don't blindly consider sourcing a file as anti-pattern. It all depends on the particular circumstances. If your *test.env* is a part of your repository being deployed, then it is surely safe to call `source test.env`. That's my opinion, however.

Comment: `-i` by itself (without a (nonempty) option-argument) doesn't work with BSD/macOS `sed`, which is the OP's primary problem.
Good revision of the `sed` command otherwise, but I'd advise against blindly sourcing `test.env` for security reasons.

Comment: @mklement0, indeed, `-i` is not portable. And that's why I recommend _not using in-place SED at all_. If _test.env_ is a trusted template with correct file system permissions, then I wouldn't call it "blindly sourcing". It actually looks like OP uses the file as template for deployment.

Comment: @mklement0, if we will call all `source`-like instructions "blind includes", then we shouldn't `#include` in C, and `include` in PHP, for example. I think it is not the case here as well.

Comment: `source` _executes_ code, which makes it a risk, at least hypothetically, that's all I wanted to point out - so thanks for adding the hint re trusted.
The `sed` command doesn't involve loading executable code, and can easily be made to work on BSD/macOS systems (just use `-i ''`), which may be all the OP needs (we don't know); also, my answer shows how to make it portable across Linux and BSD/macOS,
and, if POSIX-compliance is needed, omitting `-i` and using `> tmp.out && mv tmp.out "$Deploy_path"` will do.