# sed hanging with no results but rename works

Tags: macos, sed, rename

`find /$HOME/Desktop -name "*.dpx" -exec sed -i "" 's/Exile1/ExileR1/' {} \;`

just hangs with no results. I'm unclear what the problem may be.

Buuuut,

`find /$HOME/Desktop -name "*.dpx" -exec rename 's/Exile1/ExileR1/' {} \;`

works fine.

Why????

I'm on MacOSX.

Comment: Sed seems to think your command is `/s/Exi...` and not `s/Exil...` - have you copy-pasted the right command?

Comment: Ah, fixed that. `s/Exil...` just hangs and nothing happens...

Comment: These two commands try to do different things. Sed looks at the _content_ of the files and changes the _content_; `rename` looks at the _name_ of the files and changes the _name_. Which one do you want? (See [mklement0's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41837720/3266847).)

Comment: To those wondering about `-i ""` vs. just `-i`. `-i ""` is indeed necessary with BSD `sed`, the implementation used on macOS (you can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40777793/45375)).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you contrast your failing `sed` command with `rename`, **it looks like you're trying to *rename files*, whereas the `sed` command would perform a string substitution *in the content* of the files you pass**; the `-i` option then writes the modified input back to the input file (loosely speaking).

`sed` cannot rename files directly, but you can use it as an *auxiliary* command to construct a new filename you then pass to `mv`:

```
find "$HOME/Desktop" -name "*.dpx" -print0 | 
 while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   echo mv "$file"' "$(sed 's/Exile1/ExileR1/' <<<"$file")"
 done
```

<sup>Remove `echo` to perform actual renaming.</sup>

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 I noticed that running the sed command did change the checksum on my files. DPX are image files so I'm unclear what sed would have done to change the checksum... it doesn't alter the hex of a file just text content if present, right?

Comment: Yes, _your_ `sed` command changes the file's _content_, even if no actual substitutions take place. At the very least, BSD `sed` will append a trailing `\n` to your content. But it sounds like you just wanted to _rename_ files, not _change their content_, right?

Comment: I did just want to rename and thanks to your advice I did just that with rename. I just didn't understand what sed was actually doing in my command once I saw that the checksums had changed. If the content is simply an image then \n was added to the hex? @mklement0

Comment: BSD `sed` always adds a trailing `\n` to its output, even if the input didn't have one, so it is fundamentally unsuitable for editing _binary_ files - _GNU_ `sed` doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any .dpx files, but try adding a -e to clarify the search script. Like this...

```
find /$HOME/Desktop -name "*.dpx" -exec sed -i "" -e 's/Exile1/ExileR1/' {} \;
```

Comment: Please don't post such quick tips as an answer - use a comment instead. Use of  `-e` makes no difference here.