# sed command issues

Tags: regex, awk, sed, terminal

**Background**

Original json (`test.json`): `{"rpc-password": "password"}`

Expected changed json: `{"rpc-password": "somepassword"}`

`replace_json_str` is a function used to replace `password` with `somepassword` using `sed`.

```
replace_json_str() {
    x=$1
    sed -i -e 's/\({ "'"$2"'":\)"[^"]*" }/\1"'"$3"'" }/g' $x
}
```

Unit test: `replace_json_str test.json rpc-password somepassword`

**Issue**

After running the above test, I get a file named `test.json-e` and the contents of the file is the same as before the test was ran, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a  [handy command line json tool called jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
cat input.json
{"rpc-password": "password"}
```

cat update_json.sh

```
givenkey=$1
givenvalue=$2

inputfile=input.json
outfile=output.json

cat $inputfile  | jq .   #  show input json

jq --arg key1 "$givenkey" --arg val1 "$givenvalue"  '.[$key1] = $val1' "$inputfile" > "$outfile"

cat "$outfile" | jq .     #  render output json
```

keep in mind jq can handle multiple such key value updates ... execute it

```
update_json.sh  rpc-password somepassword
{
  "rpc-password": "password"
}
{
  "rpc-password": "somepassword"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which `sed` you're using.

The command you ran will work as expected with GNU sed.

But BSD sed does not allow for an empty argument to `-i`, and if you ran the same command, it will use the next argument, `-e`, as the backup file.

Also, the positioning of the spaces in your pattern don't match your example JSON.

Comment: Okay, so how would I change the spaces in the pattern to work?

Comment: apparently I am using BSD sed after a quick look.

Comment: I change the command to `sed -i "$1" -e 's/\({ "'"$2"'":\)"[^"]*" }/\1"'"$3"'" }/g'` inside `replace_json_str` and after running it I get `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`

Comment: That's not how you use it. It should be something like `sed -i .bak -e 's/\({"'"$2"'": \)"[^"]*"}/\1"'"$3"'"}/g' $x`. You'll end up with a `$x.bak` file which is the original, and an `$x` file which is modified.

Comment: okay that works, but I don't want a `test.json.bak` after running the script.

Comment: With BSD sed, you don't have an option to skip the backup file.

Comment: @ephemient: Actually, you do: use `-i ''`.

Comment: @mklement0 Okay, but then it doesn't work with GNU sed.

Comment: @ephemient: [Indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40777793/45375) - If you do not want a backup file created, there is no single `-i` syntax that works for both BSD and GNU sed.

Comment: Replace sed with perl -pe and will work everywhere... perl -pe has the same syntax as sed , including backreferences