# how to use awk to do a number comparisons and create a list - using Awk on macOS with CRLF line endings

Tags: macos, shell, unix, awk, line-endings

I'm trying to list values greater than my value listed (output from my `knife` command). I am trying to do this using `awk`, i've been researching examples and came up with this. However, my expected output does not work.

For example with this command, I get the following output:

```
knife ssh -x foobar -a ec2.local_ipv4 "chef_environment:prod AND roles:db_cluster AND AND ipaddress:10.1.*" 'netstat -na | grep EST | wc -l'
```

Output:

```
10.1.3.129 2273
10.1.3.130 2533
10.1.3.131 1981
10.1.2.133 1965
```

Now, I want to use `awk` because I want to filter only those values (2nd column, remove IPs) > 2000.

I tried the following `awk` statement, but to no avail

```
knife ssh -x foobar -a ec2.local_ipv4 "chef_environment:prod AND roles:db_cluster AND AND ipaddress:10.1.*" 'netstat -na | grep EST | wc -l' \
| awk '{if ($2 > 2000) print $2; else echo "Nothing to print"}`
```

Output:

```
10.1.3.129 2273
10.1.3.130 2533
10.1.3.131 1981
10.1.2.133 1965
```

Expected output:

```
2273
2533
```

Comment: Simplify: `echo "abc 2001" | awk ...` Does that do what you expected?

Comment: If your `knife` command truly produced the output stated in your question, your `awk` command would work. There must be an additional factor at play. Pipe the `knife` command to `... | cat -et` to see if there are any unexpected control characters in the output.

Comment: ahh yes @mklement0 - I'm seeing - `10.1.2.133 1282^M$` - how do i strip that?

Comment: what is your output (if any) for `uname -srv ; awk --version` ? Good luck.

Comment: @noober, there are many many many (many many) questions and answers here relating to stripping ctrl-m characters from the ends of lines. How about doing [a quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+ctrl-m)?

Comment: @shellter - ```Darwin 16.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Wed Oct 19 20:31:56 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.4~4/RELEASE_X86_64
awk version 20070501``` - I have a `^M$` to strip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The simplest approach is to remove `\r` instances from the output before passing it to `awk`:

```
knife ... | tr -d '\r' | awk ...
```

<sup>This assumes that `\r` instances only occur as part of `\r\n` pairs to designate line endings, which is generally the case.</sup>

---

From your comments, we now know that **your input has Windows-style CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings** and that you're on **macOS Sierra (10.12)**.

That said, your sample output is inconsistent with the `awk` command in your question.

Leaving that issue aside, there are **two basic approaches**:

- **(a) Translate `\r\n` (CRLF) sequences to just `\n` (LF)  *first*.**
- **(b) Work around the issue by modifying Awk's input-record separator.**

---

The following examples use simplified input and a simplified command to focus on the core issue:

- `printf '10.1.3.129 2273\r\n10.1.3.130 2533\r\n'` is used to produce 2 CRLF- terminated (`\r\n`-terminated) input lines containing 2 whitespace-separated fields each.
- `awk '{ print $2 }' | cat -e` - or a variations thereof - prints the 2nd whitespace-separated field from each line using `awk`, and `cat -e` is used to visualize control characters in the output: `$` represents a `\n` (LF) char. (the end of the line in Unix terms), and other control characters are visualized as `^<letter>`, i.e., in  [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation); therefore, `\r` (CR) is represented as `^M`.

  - By default, the `\r` would be *included* in the output, because `awk` doesn't consider it whitespace (which the lines are split into fields by) - which is clearly undesired. The output would look as follows, where `^M` indicates the unwanted inclusion of `\r`:

    ```
    2273^M$
    2533^M$
    ```
  - With an effective solution, the `\r` would *not* be included in the output, and the output would look as follows (note the absence of `^M`):

    ```
    2273$
    2533$
    ```

---

#### Solutions based on approach (a):

Most typically, **utility `dos2unix`** is used to translate Windows-style line breaks to Unix-style ones, but that utility doesn't come with macOS.
It's easy to install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), however.
Then use `knife ... | dos2unix | awk ...`.
(Alternatively send output to a file first and update that file in-place before further processing: `dos2unix file`.)

Alternatively, brought to you by the Shameless Self-Promotion Department, you can install my **[`nws` CLI](https://github.com/mklement0/nws-cli);** if you have Node.js installed, install it by simply running `[sudo] npm install -g nws-cli` and then use `knife ... | nws --lf | awk ...`.
(Alternatively, send output to a file first and update that file in-place before further processing:
`nws --lf -i file`; `nws` can also translate from LF to CRLF and offers other whitespace-related functions.)

There are also fairly simple ways to **use stock macOS utilities** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641770/45375) of mine.

The simplest solution with stock utilities is to use `tr` to blindly remove any `\r` instances:

```
$ printf '10.1.3.129 2273\r\n10.1.3.130 2533\r\n' |
    tr -d '\r' | awk '{ print $2 }' | cat -e
2273$
2533$
```

---

#### Solution based on approach (b):

```
$ printf '10.1.3.129 2273\r\n10.1.3.130 2533\r\n' |
    awk -v RS='\r' 'NF {print $2}' | cat -e
2273$
2533$
```

Note how `-v RS='\r'` defines `\r` as `RS`, the input-record separator, which means that it is automatically excluded from each record (line) that `awk` reads and splits into fields.

`NF`, placed as a *condition* before the action (`{...}`) is necessary to eliminate the empty line that results from reading the final `\n` as a separate record.

- This could be avoided if we *could* define `RS` as `\r\n`, but, sadly, the BSD Awk on macOS doesn't support multi-character input-record separators (in line with the [POSIX spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)).
  Via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), however, you could install *GNU* Awk, which does support such separators, which would simplify the command to:
  `gawk -v RS='\r\n' '{print $2}'`

Comment: thanks @mklement0! appreciate the details and different solutions!