# Bash: Can't append a string to an existing string - it appears to overwrite the start of that string instead

Tags: string, bash, line-endings

This is a script that helps us in creating a dhcpd.conf file.

sample inputs (ex. mac-tab-;-tab-IP)

```
DC:D3:21:75:61:90   ;   10.25.131.17
    ;
```

expected outputs

```
Host 27-48 { hardware ethernet DC:D3:21:75:61:90 ; fixed-address 10.25.131.17 ; }

#host 27-48 { hardware ethernet ; fixed-address ; }
```

Currently the line outputted is this:

```
Host 27-48 { hardware ethernet 00:16:6B:C8:3D:C9 ; fixed-address 10.25.129.185
```

Specific line in code I'm stuck on

```
outputLine="Host $((names[i]))-$((startingNumber+counter)) { hardware ethernet $first ; fixed-address $second"
```

If I try adding ; }

```
outputLine="Host $((names[i]))-$((startingNumber+counter)) { hardware ethernet $first ; fixed-address $second ; }"
```

I get this:

```
; } 27-48 { hardware ethernet 00:16:6B:C8:3D:C9 ; fixed-address 10.25.129.185
```

The issue is, whenever I append " ; }" to the end of the above line, it overwrites the beginning of the line.  I've tried a few tricks to work around it, such as writing the above line to a string, and then trying to append to the string, but the same issue occurs.  I had an idea to export the entire contents to a file, and re-reload the file into an array just so I can append, but it seems a little overkill.

```
for ((j=1; j<=${sizes[i]}; j++ )); do

    #split line, read split as two entries for an arrIN
    IN=(${line[counter+1]})
    arrIN=(${IN//;/ })
    first="${arrIN[0]}"
    second=${arrIN[1]}


    if [ ${lineSize[counter+1]} -gt 5 ]
    then
        #sed 's/$/ ; }/' $outputLine > newoutputLine
        outputLine="Host $((names[i]))-$((startingNumber+counter)) { hardware ethernet $first ; fixed-address $second"
        echo $outputLine
    else
        echo "#host $((names[i])) $((startingNumber+counter)) { hardware ethernet ; fixed-address ; }"
    fi
    counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Comment: Try printing `$second` -- may be there's something funny at the end of `${arrIN[1]}`

Comment: State your input variables clearly and provide an exact expected output.  Is your `bash` code creating the `dhcpd.conf` file or you just want to edit that file in-place with the `; }` at end?

Comment: updated sample input.  Bash code is not creating dhcpd.conf, but just a section of it which will ultimately be merged with a subnet portion (i.e. copy and pasted).  One output has already been provided, will update the output for the other "blank case"

Comment: just a hunch, I would change the `echo $outputLine` into `echo "$outputLine"`

Comment: There must be a carriage return sneaking in (that is, your input must have Windows line endings). Try running, say, `second="${second//$'\r'/}"` to snip it out.

Comment: the input were columns in excel, pasted into either notepad or notepad++.  I'll try that, thanks.  That just might be it.  Edit: That was it!  Thank you so much!  If you add this as an answer, I will upvote it.  I thought it was a "special characters" issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) explains in a comment on the question, the **problem was a CR (`0xD`, `\r`) character at the end of the value of variable `$second`**, which **can be removed with the following [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe): `second="${second//$'\r'/}"`**.

The rest of this answer explains the symptom and provides background information.

---

> The issue is, whenever I append " ; }" to the end of the above line, it overwrites the beginning of the line.

**"overwriting the beginning of a line" almost always points to an embedded [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (`0xD`, `\r`) character**, which, when a string is printed to the terminal, gives the *appearance* of overwriting the start of the line:

```
$ printf 'abc\rd'  # `printf '\r'` produces a CR 
dbc  # It LOOKS LIKE 'd' replaced 'a', but that's an artifact of printing to the terminal.
```

It is only because the terminal interprets the CR (`\r`) as "place the cursor at the start of the line" that `d` - the remaining string after `\r` - appears to "overwrite" the start of the already-printed part of the string.

**You can visualize embedded CRs (and other control characters) with `cat -et`**, which represents them in [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) as **`^M`**:

```
$ printf 'abc\rd' | cat -et
abc^Md   # ^M represents a CR (\r)
```

As you can see, the `d` didn't actually *overwrite* `a`, the start of the string.

---

**CR (`\r`) instances are rarely used in the world of *Unix* text processing. If they do appear as part of text data, it is usually from *Windows*-originated sources that use CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings rather than the Unix LF-only (`\n`) line endings.**

**Often, the simplest approach is to simply *remove* the CR (`\r`) instances *before* using the data with Unix utilities**.

There are many, many existing answers that cover this territory, often recommending use of **third-party utility [`dos2unix`](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/)**, easily installable via the package managers of many platforms (e.g., `sudo apt install dos2unix` on Ubunutu, or `brew install dos2unix` on macOS, via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)).

Alternatively,

- for text already stored in a variable, use [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)'s approach based on parameter expansion; e.g.,  `second="${second//$'\r'/}"`
- for files, [solutions using standard utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641770/45375) can act as a makeshift `dos2unix`.